# Tkinter - can't type into entry widget after restoring the window with wm_state('normal') function

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't find any solution, so I hope you will help me.

I'm using in my project entry widgets and wm_state('iconic') and wm_state('normal) function. Unfortunatelly after restoring tkinter main window by using wm_state('normal) function I'm unable to use entry widget. Manually minimizing and restoring the window solves the problem. Do you have any idea, how can I avoid it? Below is the testing code I prepared for better understanding. Thank you for the help. I thought root.withdraw() is the solution, but unfortunately, program disappears then from the taskbar, what is not good in my case.

```
import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import ttk    
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

def test_function():
    root.wm_state('iconic')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    root.wm_state('normal')


button = tk.Button(root, text='MINIMIZE BUTTON', command=test_function)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

entrywidget = tk.Entry(root, width='10')
entrywidget.grid(row=1, column=0)

entrywidget.focus()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem on OSX. When the window is restored I can continue to type into the entry. What platform are you on? Have you tried restoring the focus inside of `test_function`?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to restore the focus inside of test_function and I was even calling it from other functions (just for testing), but still couldn't figure out, what's wrong. I'm on Win10 64bit. I tested it on Python 3.7 (64-bit), Python 3.7 (32-bit) and Python 3.8 (32-bit). Maybe the Python version is the issue? What version did you test it on?

Comment: I doubt it's the python version. It's probably a platform issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
root.withdraw()     
root.deiconify()
```

Instead of:

```
root.wm_state('iconic')
root.wm_state('normal')
```

Solves the entry widget problem, but program is no longer visible on the taskbar after root.withdraw() until root.deiconify() method call.